# use MySQL select an not exists row for update returns deadlock?

Tags: java, mysql

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Two threads work like this ( there is no record's id equal to 1001)

```
begin;
select * from tableA where id = 1001 for update;
insert into tableA select 1001, 'nameA';
commit;
```

- Both threadA and threadB ***select ... for update*** run success
- ThreadB get deadlock when try to ***insert*** before ThreadA ***commit***;

I know MySQL support ***Next-Key Lock*** and ***Gap Lock*** to lock Index, but why both threadA and threadB can successfully lock Index?

what's more, how does this deadlock happen?

---

update for more information

in this below example, threadB will wait until threadA commit if threadA ***select ... for update*** execute successfully although there is no record's id equal to 1001.

threadA

```
begin;
select * from tableA where id = 1001 for update;
insert into tableA select 1001, 'nameA';
commit;
```

threadB

```
insert into tableA select 1001, 'nameA';
```

So I am sure although 1001 not exists, but with ***select ... for update*** MySQL still lock the index to prevent others to insert 1001, but two thread lock the index with same range has no conflict, that makes me a lot of confused.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html *If you use FOR UPDATE with a storage engine that uses page or row locks, rows examined by the query are **write-locked** until the end of the current transaction.* There is NO read lock, so both threads performs SELECT successfully. But 1st thread locks the row - it can update whereas 2nd needs the commit which releases the table.

Comment: ... if the 2nd thread execites insert firstly - then 1st will wait until commit in 2nd, write locks have no ordering or priority.

Comment: You must use a `table-lock` to do that, causing concurrent inserts to run serially. `select ... for update` doesn't work in your case because row with id = 1001 doesn't exist before the insert.